# SQL Server select query taking long time to execute with WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have one table `Table1` which contains 1 - 1.5 million of rows with a primary key.

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [Id] [INT] NOT NULL,    
    [allow_public] [BIT] NULL,
    [average_frequency] [DECIMAL](18, 4) NULL,
    [category_id] [INT] NULL,
    -- a few more columns
    --
    --
    --
    [member_id] [INT] NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1_Id] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

Added a nonclustered index on `member_id` like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX non_cluster_index_member_table1
    ON dbo.Table1 (member_id) 
    WHERE member_id IS NOT NULL;
    GO
```

When I execute query like

```
SELECT
    [id], 
    [accurate_grams],
    [allow_public],
    [average_frequency],
    [category_id]
FROM
    dbo.Table1 
WHERE 
    member_id = @memberid;
```

it returns some rows within milliseconds. But when I execute a query like

```
SET @OrgMemberId = ISNULL(@OrgMemberId, -1);

SELECT
    [id], 
    [accurate_grams],
    [allow_public],
    [average_frequency],
    [category_id]
FROM 
    dbo.Table1 f
WHERE 
    ISNULL(f.member_id, -1) = CASE 
                                 WHEN @MemberId = -1 
                                    THEN ISNULL(f.member_id, -1) 
                                    ELSE @MemberId 
                              END
```

it takes lot of time to complete execution.

**Note**: `member_id` column contains null values. And it is not mapped as a foreign key

```
    ISNULL(f.member_id, -1) = CASE 
                                 WHEN @MemberId = -1 
                                    THEN ISNULL(f.member_id, -1) 
                                    ELSE @MemberId 
                              END
```

Reason to write above line is - sometimes users send null value to `@MemberId`. To handle this scenario I have used this line in where clause. In single query I can fetch two different results. When `member_id is null` then query select all records and when `member_id is not null` then query select only those records matches with `Member_id`. So there is no need to use `if else`.

Is there any other solution to handle this?

Comment: Why do you need that check? I don't see the point: if you know already that you wont find any resilult, why running the query? Anyway, you could use `coalesce` instead, that would help a little. But maybe I have misunderstood your edit. Please expleain and post the complete statement (can skip exact columns, as before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach would be to use a **covering** index - an index that contains *all* the columns your query needs to return:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ncix_table1_member_id
ON dbo.Table1 (member_id) 
INCLUDE (id, accurate_grams, allow_public, average_frequency, category_id)
WHERE member_id IS NOT NULL;
GO
```

With this approach, now your query can be "satisfied" by just looking at the index - and it doesn't have to do a lot of (fairly expensive) "key lookups" into the actual table's data pages to fetch the "missing" column values for your query

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have 10 to 15 columns. So I include to add all these columns?

Comment: If I include all these columns then does it affects on any performance issue  on insert,delete,update operation?

Comment: I have just started my Studio and tried my old code which is in post and it's working perfectly fine. Giving result in millisecond. I don't know what was the issue.

Comment: The index is only **covering** if it includes **ALL** the columns your query needs - so yes, if your query needs 15 columns, you have to include them all in the covering index. And yes, of course, any index will cost a tiny little bit of extra time to maintain - it's a **trade-off** between faster query performance for `SELECT` vs. more overhead for other operations -  only you can decide whether it's worth it